# Creating text files with a random list of unsorted integers

Tags: c#, text-files

Below is my attempt at a method that randomly generates integers, but sometimes it gives me less integers than I wanted or, it won't even write them to the file.

```
//generates random integers and moves it into respective file
static void Randomgen(int Size)         
{
    StreamWriter SW = new StreamWriter("Test.txt");     // respective file
    Random random = new Random();  
             
    for (int i = 0; i < Size; i++)
    {
        SW.WriteLine(random.Next(0, int.MaxValue));
    }
}
```

and then I call it into the main using

```
Randomgen(100);
Console.ReadLine();
```

so this is all part of a bigger project. I have to sort these integers, and test the different sorts and their efficiency over different file sizes. I just don't know why sometimes it works, and sometimes it doesnt, and when it does it generates just shy of whatever I input into the `Randomgen`method. Please someone explain why this is happening. Also, when I try using the method with smaller sizes like 10 it just creates the blank text file with no list of integers.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.
Please take the [tour] to learn how Stack Overflow works and read [ask] on how to improve the quality of your question.
Then [edit] your question to include the full source code you have as a [mcve], which can be compiled and tested by others.
Please see: [What Do You Mean “It Doesn't Work”?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/147616)

Comment: Lets say i try to create a file nd pick a bigger size like a 100, it creates a file with 90 values  and if create a file with a size smaller size like 10 it just creates an empty file

Answer (score 4):

.Net streams are buffered, so you need to flush stream after writing to it, so either explicitly call `SW.Flush()` at end, or, more correctly, dispose of stream with declaring it with a [using statement](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/using-statement):

```
static void Randomgen(int Size) {
  using (var SW = new StreamWriter("Test.txt")) { // using
    var random = new Random();                   
    for (int i = 0; i < Size; i++) {
      SW.WriteLine(random.Next(0, int.MaxValue));
    }
  }
}
```

C# 8.0+ `using` syntax:

```
static void Randomgen(int Size) {
  using var SW = new StreamWriter("Test.txt"); // using
  var random = new Random();                   
  for (int i = 0; i < Size; i++) {
    SW.WriteLine(random.Next(0, int.MaxValue));
  }
}
```

Comment: Changed to old 'using' syntax

Comment: thnx. theres a syntax error by using, if you dont have version 8.0 of vs. So i just use the flush function

Comment: Calling `Flush` isn't exception-safe, whereas using the [dispose pattern](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/garbage-collection/implementing-dispose) together with `using` is.

Comment: The Random object is declared in the wrong place. It should be a static Field.